# How to share variables between routes in Flask (python)

Tags: python, flask, routes

I am trying to use sessions to share variables among routes in Flask. This is the code I am using:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, session
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_session import Session

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

SESSION_TYPE = 'filesystem'
app.config.from_object(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'abc'

@app.route("/getinputData", methods = ['POST'])
def getData():
    inputData = json.loads(request.data)
    molID = inputData["ID"]
    searchType = inputData["searchType"]
    session["sharedmolID"] = molID
    session["sharedsearchType"] = searchType
    return inputData

@app.route("/querydatabyMol", methods = ['GET'])
def querydatabyMol():
    sharedmolID = session.get("sharedmolID", None)
    sharedsearchType = session.get("sharedsearchType", None)
    print(sharedmolID)
    print(sharedsearchType)
    return sharedmolID

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

sess = Session()
sess.init_app(app)
```

But when the second route prints the variables I get None. I have temporarily solved this using global variables, but I read that they are not thread safe, so I would like to use sessions.

Any idea of what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing the "session.get()" Method with:

```py
@app.route("/querydatabyMol", methods = ['GET'])
def querydatabyMol():
    sharedmolID = session["sharedmolID"]
    sharedsearchType = session["sharedsearchType"]
    print(sharedmolID)
    print(sharedsearchType)
    return sharedmolID
```

also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15591656/15504463) for a related problem

Comment: I had previously tried accessing the variables like that, but I get the following error: KeyError: 'sharedmolID'. I think that there is a problem on how I initialize the session, and the variables do not get stored properly, but I do not know how to fix it

Comment: have you tried printing `molID = inputData["ID"]`? Just to be sure there is no weird stuff going on at another point

Comment: Yes, it prints a string and actually it works for the approach of global variables